# Количество пар, удовлетворяющих условию, и их сумма

Tags: python, python-3.x, перебор

> В файле содержится последовательность из 10 000 натуральных чисел.
> Каждое число не превышает 10 000. Определите и запишите в ответе
> сначала количество пар элементов последовательности, у которых
> различные остатки от деления на d  =  160 и хотя бы одно из чисел
> делится на p  =  7, затем максимальную из сумм элементов таких пар.
>
> В данной задаче под парой подразумевается два различных элемента
> последовательности. Порядок элементов в паре не важен.

Вопрос - как оптимизировать код (медленное выполнение)?

```py
a = [int(x) for x in open('17.txt')]
s = 0 #кол-во пар под условия
mx = 0 #максимал сумма
for i in range(len(a) - 1): 
    for j in range(i + 1, len(a)):
        if (a[i] % 160 != a[j] % 160) and ((a[i] % 7 == 0) or (a[j] % 7 == 0)):
            s += 1
            mx = max(mx, a[i] + a[j])
print(s, mx) # > 12749665 19989
```

[txt](https://easyupload.io/7lvx21)

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Могу посоветовать кешировать остатки от деления `a[i]` на 160 и на 7. Также, если `a[i] % 7 == 0`, то не проверять `a[j] % 7 == 0`, а сразу принимать, что эта часть условия *истина* (так как имеется одно значение *истина* в цепочке с `or`). Еще можно разделить выполнение на несколько потоков. Но, на самом деле, вам это не нужно. Это задача из ЕГЭ, а значит вам требуется выполнить ее только один раз и записать ответ. Да, придется подождать секунд 10-20, но это нормально для почти 50.000.000 итераций.

Comment: используйте словарь для хранения сумм элементов по каждому возможному остатку от деления на 160, которые уже были просмотрены, а затем только для каждого нового элемента вычислять суммы с теми, которые уже встретились ранее

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разбейте всё множество на *320* корзин. Число *n* попадёт в корзину с индексом *(int(n % 7 == 0), n % 160)*. В каждой корзине хранятся не сами числа, а их количество и максимум.

Перебирайте пары корзин. Если пара корзин подходит для составления пар чисел, то к количеству пар чисел добавляется произведение количеств чисел в этих корзинах. Максимум суммы также обновляется с помощью суммы максимумов в корзинах.

Время работы включает размещение по корзинам - *O(n)* и обработку пар корзин - *320 * 319 / 2 = 51040* операций. В вашем варианте операций может быть до *10000 * 9999 / 2 = 49995000*. 50 тысяч куда лучше чем 50 миллионов.

```
d = {}
with open('.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        n = int(line)
        p = d.setdefault((n % 7 == 0, n % 160), [0, 0])
        p[0] += 1
        p[1] = max(n, p[1])

b = [(r7, r160, k, m) for (r7, r160), (k, m) in d.items()]

count = 0
max_ = 0
for i in range(len(b)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(b)):
        if b[i][0] or b[j][0]: # 7 divides at least one
            if b[i][1] != b[j][1]: # different moduli 160
                count += b[i][2] * b[j][2]
                max_ = max(max_, b[i][3] + b[j][3])

print(count, max_)
```

> ```
> $ time python 17.py
> 12749665 19989
>
> real  0m0.064s
> user  0m0.064s
> sys   0m0.000s
> ```

Но и это ещё не всё. Если вы разобрались как устроены корзины, то идём дальше. Сложность можно уменьшить до *O(n) + 320*. Для этого все корзины соберём в прямоугольный массив `grid` размера *160 * 2*. Первое измерение *mod 160*, второе по делимости на *7*.

Сочетаем корзины `grid[i][x]` c предыдущими по правилу:

```
grid[i][0] и grid[< i][1] *
grid[i][1] и grid[< i][0]
grid[i][1] и grid[< i][1]
```

** `grid[< i][x]` - означает любую корзину с первым индексом меньше `i`.*

Таких сочетаний будет `3 * 160 * 159 / 2 = 38160`. Но корзины вида `grid[< i][x]` можно накапливать в аккумуляторах `acc[x]`. Тогда сочетания будут:

```
grid[i][0] и acc[1]    # acc[x] накапливает grid[< i][x]
grid[i][1] и acc[0]
grid[i][1] и acc[1]
```

Что приводит к следующей программе:

```
# basket is an array of basket[0] - quantity of items, basket[1] = max of items
# [0, 0] - empty basket
# [1, item] - basket with one item inside


def add(target, source):
    """Add source basket into target one."""
    target[0] += source[0]
    target[1] = max(target[1], source[1])


# grid of 160*2 empty baskets (indices i, j)
grid = [[[0, 0] for _ in range(2)] for _ in range(160)]

# distribute items into backets
with open('17.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        n = int(line)
        i = n % 160
        j = int(n % 7 == 0)
        add(grid[i][j], [1, n])

# accumulating baskets (index j)
acc = [[0, 0] for _ in range(2)]

count = 0
max_ = 0
for i in range(160):
    for j1 in range(2):
        for j2 in range(2):
            if j1 > 0 or j2 > 0: # 7 divides some of items
                count +=         acc[j1][0] * grid[i][j2][0]
                max_ = max(max_, acc[j1][1] + grid[i][j2][1])

    for j in range(2):
        add(acc[j], grid[i][j])

print(count, max_)
```

> ```
> $ time python 17_2.py
> 12749665 19989
>
> real  0m0.038s
> user  0m0.036s
> sys   0m0.004s
> ```

Из 0.038c общего времени 0.026c занимают запуск Питон и чтение файла. На сами вычисления уходит примерно 0.012с.

Последний вариант хорошо масштабируется на, скажем, десятки и сотни миллиардов чисел (числа не хранятся в памяти) и миллионы корзин (корзины хранятся, обрабатываются за линейное время).

Comment: Интересно. А этот же принцип применим к задаче...?
F(0) = 0,
F(n) = F(n-1) + 1 (n%2 != 0), 
F(n) = F(n//2) (n%2 == 0),
найти кол-во n в диапазоне [0;1_000_000_000] для F(n)=3

Comment: Нет. Это две совершенно разные задачи.